Remove random generated numbers fron a line with sed
I'm trying to set-up my RSS feed images for my HA server.
Basically the line I need to edit looks like this:
<enclosure length="267527" type="image/jpeg" url="image.jpg"/>

And I want it to look like this:
<picture_a>image.jpg</picture_a>

The numbers in length are always different so using something like this wouldn't work:
sed -i 's!<<enclosure length="267527" type="image/jpeg" url="!<picture_a>!g' /config/www/feed.rss

I'm really not familiar with this command, it's actually my first time using it.
Anyone would have some pointers and help me out?

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's#<enclosure length=".*" type="image/jpeg" url="\(.*\)"/>#<picture_a>\1</picture_a>#' file

Pattern match the string you want to replace, using .* between double quotes for length and url. Also keep a copy of the string between double quotes for the url using a back reference and insert it in the replacement string.
If you want to be a little more precise, replace the first .* by [0-9]\+ to restrict length to one or more digits and the second .* by \S\+ for url to one or more non-white spaces.

FWIW that'll work in any sed, not just GNU. I know that because I can understand it :-).

@EdMorton ... except the \S in the final suggestion which is a GNU sed extension.

You can use this Perl one-liner:
perl -i.bak -lpe 's{.*url="([^"]+)".*}{<picture_a>$1</picture_a>}' /config/www/feed.rss

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-p : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default. Add print $_ after each loop iteration.
-l : Strip the input line separator ("\n" on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
-i.bak : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension .bak. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use -i and skip the extension.
s{PATTERN}{REPLACEMENT} : Replace regex PATTERN with REPLACEMENT.
.* : Any character, repeated 0 or more times.
([^"]+) : Any character except double quote ("), repeated 1 or more times. The result is captured into the match variable $1, which is later used in the substitution.
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches
perldoc perlrequick: Perl regular expressions quick start

